# Going mutex-less

Tags: go, concurrency

Alright, Go "experts". How would you write this code in idiomatic Go, aka without a mutex in `next`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan int)
    x := 0
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            y := next(&x)
            fmt.Println(y)
            done <- 0
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        <-done
    }
    fmt.Println(x)

}

var mutex = make(chan int, 1)

func next(p *int) int {
    mutex <- 0
    // critical section BEGIN
    x := *p
    *p++
    // critical section END
    <-mutex
    return x

}
```

Assume you can't have two goroutines in the critical section at the same time, or else bad things will happen.

My first guess is to have a separate goroutine to handle the state, but I can't figure out a way to match up inputs / outputs.

Comment: Use `atomic.Value` from `sync/atomic`?

Answer (score 3):

You would use an actual sync.Mutex:

```
var mutex sync.Mutex

func next(p *int) int {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()
    x := *p
    *p++
    return x
}
```

Though you would probably also group the `next` functionality, state and sync.Mutex into a single struct.

Though there's no reason to do so in this case, since a Mutex is better suited for mutual exclusion around a single resource, you can use goroutines and channels to achieve the same effect

http://play.golang.org/p/RR4TQXf2ct

```
x := 0

var wg sync.WaitGroup
send := make(chan *int)
recv := make(chan int)

go func() {
    for i := range send {
        x := *i
        *i++
        recv <- x
    }
}()

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        send <- &x
        fmt.Println(<-recv)
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println(x)
```

Comment: You answer to "Going mutex-less" is "use a mutex"? I'm sorry, that's not the right answer. I know I could have done it that way, but I'm looking for the "correct" way, aka message-passing with channels.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn: That is a correct way, and the most common. You asked for the advice of a "go expert", and this is the way we would do it (for one, check how often this pattern is used throughout the std library).

Comment: @BrianMalehorn: added an example with channels and a goroutine for synchronizing access

Comment: Eh, I'll use a mutex if you say it's the right way.

However, the above code has a race. Thread 1 executes `send <- p`, thread 2 executes `send <- q`, thread 2 executes `<-recv` and thread 1 executes `<-recv`. Now they get each other's responses.

This would be an issue if you changed the above code a little: http://play.golang.org/p/ruNsFSgJau

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking that the channels were buffered. The above code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As @favoretti mentioned, sync/atomic is a way to do it.

But, you have to use int32 or int64 rather than int (since int can be different sizes on different platforms).

Here's an example on [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/_QgkKfGoUj)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan int)
    x := int64(0)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            y := next(&x)
            fmt.Println(y)
            done <- 0
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        <-done
    }
    fmt.Println(x)

}

func next(p *int64) int64 {
    return atomic.AddInt64(p, 1) - 1
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's not really what I meant. What would you do if it was `*p = (*p + 1) * 5`? Or really anything that doesn't have an `atomic` version.

Comment: as was already said, I'd use sync.Mutex in your example.  Channels are too heavy of a construct to be used as a pure mutex.  It somewhat depends on the complexity of the critical section as to what to do, but in general, I wouldn't use a channel unless I can cary on with other actions asynchronously.